# Downsampling an audio signal, removing outlier values due to transistional spikes in the signal

Tags: signal-processing, algorithm

I have an audio signal as following:
[image]

I'm looking for a way to extract only the constant parts (in red,) or in other words, remove the outliers (in green.) I have very little knowledge in signal processing.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Sample coherently with whatever is driving it. Alternately, perform some analog integration (low pass filtering) so as to mitigate the spikiness.

Comment: Pass it through a median filter, that's exactly what it's built for.

Comment: You are aware that [color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) is a thing, and that red-green colorblindness is the most common form of it, yes?  Using different shapes (circles and 'X's, for instance) instead of or in addition to color-coding, would increase your available pool of question-answerers by at least 5%, possibly more.

Comment: You say "downsampling" -- do you mean to say that the "flat spots" in the signal occur at a constant interval?  I.e., is the signal characterized by "edge - flat - edge - flat", etc., and the duration of the flats is constant?  And do you _just_ want the values of the "flats", at a much-reduced data rate?  If so, _edit your question_ to include that information.

Comment: You can use [matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/remove-spikes-from-a-signal.html). Essentially you are doing low pass filtering of your signal.

Comment: You may want to analyze what's going on in your analog domain - those crazy samples look like out-of-band erroneous samples rather than valid audio samples.

Answer (score 4):

Best way would be to synchronize sampling at points when the voltage is stabilized so you don't get these interferences. Since the points you're interested in look like they occur at periodic intervals, this would be the simplest way: just synchronize and take the sample in the middle of the flat areas.

Failing that, if the length of the flats is variable, and if you want to remove spikes, keep the flats, and also measure the length of the flats...

Method 1:

Spikes have high derivative, flats have low derivative. So, simply compute the absolute value of the derivative of the signal, apply some moving average smoothing to it, and compare to a threshold. That will give you a true/false value if the sample is part of a spike or not. Then you can delete the spikes, or fill them in with the nearest neighbor that is not part of a spike. This method is mostly O(n) and uses vector operations so it should be pretty quick.

Method 2:

Just apply run-length compression. Set an index i0 at the beginning of the file, set an index i=i0, then scan i forward one sample at a time, computing the difference between sample[i]-sample[i0]. If that difference stays below a threshold, then the interval [i0:i] is a flat portion of the waveform, so keep increasing i until you hit a sample with sample[i]-sample[i0]>threshold.  If the length i-i0 is over a threshold, mark it as a flat portion. If it is too short, ignore it. Then set i0=i to scan the next portion of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do a Fourier transform and then analyze the result since all green points are located in places with big change(high frequencies) and then apply a proper low pass filter so all green point will diminish although there will be some side effects on edges depend on your LPF

Answer (score 0):

Use a "moving average filter".
Basically, it works in such a way that a moving average of the last x sample is taken. this will remove the noise and peaks from the signal. This is the simplest implementation of a digital low-pass filter.

Comment: "Moving average" is what people who have no knowledge of signal processing call a square-window FIR filter. About the only good thing you can say about it is that it's simple to implement, but it isn't the simplest: An IIR filter with a one-sample window is even simpler:  \$O_n=\alpha{}I_n+(1-\alpha{})O_{n-1}\$ where \$I\$ are the inputs, \$O\$ are the outputs, and \$\alpha{}\$ is a parameter, \$0<\alpha{}<=1\$.